# Evaluating PySpark UDF arguments during runtime

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a udf registered to pyspark which is tasked to query the web by building the url using the function's arguments a and b. During runtime it evaluates the arguments to `Column<b'(colA + colB)'>` at the print statement.

How do I get to the string in the arguments a and b?

```
def udf_func(a, b):
    print(a + b)
    return requests.get(a + b)

get = udf(udf_func, ByteType())
df = df.withColumn("output", get(col("colA"), col("colB")))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your function as follows :

```
def udf_func(a, b): return requests.get(a + b)

get = udf(lambda a,b : udf_func(a,b), ByteType())
df = df.withColumn("output", get(col("colA"), col("colB")))
```

I do not believe you can print values inside a *udf*  hence I have removed it but this should work for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help! Weirdly this solution didn't work for me as it left spark running indefinitely. I managed to find another work around using `concat`

Comment: If you can avoid using an UDF, please do. Like you observed, on large datasets, they will definitely slow down the run. It's best of you use spark DataFrame or SQL APIs for your code